# What is the equivalent of Owin WebApp.Start in ASP.NET Core 6 without Owin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

We're migrating our solution from .NET Framework to .NET 6 and one of the side-effects of this is getting rid of Owin, since .NET 6 seems to provide most of the tools (*.e.g.* middleware) out of the box.

We're using self-hosting via [Owin `WebApp.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn300272(v%3dvs.113)) in some of our tests, but obviously we have to replace that.

So what is the equivalent in .NET 6? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What used to be the Owin's pipeline and webApp.Start flow, has now been migrated, though the minimal apis, to something like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); // app builder
var app = builder.Build(); // app
....
app.Run(); // actually setup the app server to listen to connections

// await app.StartAsync(); // or an other approach to start the application and continue with other stuff
```

Have a look [at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more info on the net6 app abstractions

For more info on base app/hosts and their differences, also have a [look here](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-3-exploring-the-code-behind-webapplicationbuilder/)

Comment: Thanks! What about `IHostBuilder`? How are those different?

Comment: The host builder is the net5 abstraction, that is still used behind webApp builder. It used to take care of setting up the "host that will serve the app" pretty much. A WebApplication is a special kind of "app" ( its web-focued ), and you could have a setup with an ihostbuilder that hosts a non-web app ( that only contains long running tasks lets say )